# HashMap getting value by the Key

Tags: kotlin

How to compare each char from the String with Keys from the HashMap?
I have used loops of course and change each Key to Char.

```
val romanNumbers = HashMap<String, Int>()
            romanNumbers[""] = 0
            romanNumbers["I"] = 1
            romanNumbers["V"] = 5
```

Instead of string.get(i) I also tried string[i]

```
for (i in string.indices){

            for ((k, v) in romanNumbers) {
                if (string.length == 1) {
                    res1 = romanNumbers.getValue(string)
                }

                if (string.get(i) == k.single()) {
                    num1 = v

                }
                if (string[i + 1] == k.single()) {
                    num2 = v
                }
         }
     }
```

error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: Char sequence is empty.
    at kotlin.text.StringsKt___StringsKt.single(_Strings.kt:223)
    at CodeWars.MappingTrainingKt.decode(MappingTraining.kt:38)
    at CodeWars.MappingTrainingKt.main(MappingTraining.kt:4)
    at CodeWars.MappingTrainingKt.main(MappingTraining.kt)
```

Comment: You're trying to call `CharSequence.single()` on `""`, which will clearly throw an exception. There's no character to get! Also one you've fixed that issue, `string[i + 1]` will eventually be out of bounds.

Comment: I've got if in that occasion [i+1], that's True! I will fix in the momenty